# Created By User Notified Of Status Change Of List Item

Tags: list, alert, custom-alert-templates

I'm creating a list on sharepoint to use as a backup should our primary incident reporting software go down as it did this past week. I've got most everything set up the way I would like, however I need the ability to easily notify users that their issue status has changed. Is there some way to set up a field so that when the status column changes from "new request" to anything else it will automatically send an e-mail out to the created by user?

Thanks for your help!
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to use an on change workflow that sends an email to the Created By user. This will allow you to fully mimmic an existing email sent from your other system and be easier to implement and maintain over an alert template.